# use ltrim and itrim

Tags: sql, isnull

I want to write a stored procedure in order to filter some columns in which some of them might be NULL or not. code below is mine, but it does not work.

```
 procedure .[s p_organization](@expert nvarchar(100), 
  @name nvarchar(100), @last_name nvarchar(200), 
  @organization n varchar(200) )




where 
  ((Person.expert LIKE @expert or  Person.expert LIKE @expert) 
  and (is null(l trim(r trim @last_name)),'')='' 
  or person.last_name like @last_name + '%' 
  and  Person.Name LIKE @name 
  or @name is null 
  and Organization.Name LIKE N'%'+@organization +'%' )
```

Comment: Where is the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: That is invalid standard SQL. Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Too many syntactical and logical mistakes present in the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `( )` when using `or` and `and` mixed:

- `A AND B OR C` will return `C` totally independent of `A AND B`.
- `A AND (B OR C) will return`A AND B`or`A AND C` (depending on the content of the data

In your case:

```
  ((Person.expert LIKE @expert or  Person.expert LIKE @expert) 
  and ((is null(l trim(r trim @last_name)),")=" 
  or person.last_name like @last_name + '%')
  and  (Person.Name LIKE @name 
  or @name is null )
  and Organization.Name LIKE N'%'+@organization +'%' )
```

might work better (you need to tune it for your own purposes and results

Comment: I was not expecting it to solve your complete problem since I do not know where you want your `or` statements to act on. `or` statements however do need the `( )` for correct behavior when used in a complex statement as yours is.